# Spring Social Google - maven dependency not found

Tags: maven, spring-social, spring-social-google

I cannot find maven dependency for spring-social-google (https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google). 
According to the documentation the dependency is defined like that:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.social-google-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

However it is not present in maven repository.
Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Just for curiosity, is the org.springframework.social-google-version property defined in your POM? If yes, for which value?

Comment: of course it was. What a stupid mistake.... there was an extra ">" sign in front of the version number :( I did not read the maven error properly, I just assumed it is problem with finding the artifact in the maven repository...

Answer (score 1):

According to Maven repository, the [latest](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-google/1.0.0.RELEASE) version of spring-social-google is 1.0.0.RELEASE, as following:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Adding it to your POM should be enough. In your case you are using a placeholder for the version, `${org.springframework.social-google-version}`.

Hence, in your POM, you should have something as following:

```
<properties>
   <org.springframework.social-google-version>1.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.social-google-version>
</properties>
```

Maven will replace the property value in your dependency declaration and resolve it.